# Will breaking a Windows 10 app into multiple exe's improve concurrency?

Tags: c#, windows, real-time

I have a real time video processing application running on Windows 7/10 that has 4 distinct processing steps. Each of these steps is currently running in a WPF Task and I have eliminated copying of the video data as much as is possible, I am down to two copy operations. The capture of the video and the subsequent storing of the video is handled by a COM-based SDK. Would I see an increase in performance if I turned each of the steps into a separate exe and use a shared memory scheme to move the data between the exe's? Or rather than use WPF Tasks, use threads? Anyone have hard data on something like this?

Thanks,
Doug

Comment: Who knows.  You just asked a super blanket question.  What SDK?  What's it doing?  What version?

Comment: It might help. Tasks might help. Threads might help. You'll need to test to be sure. https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Answer (score 5):

Q: Will breaking a Windows 10 app into multiple exe's improve concurrency?

This question is very wide/broad, but as a generic answer: No

Parallel/concurrent performance is based on Windows scheduler which is based on threads and their priorities. It means that processes do not matter. You can have 10 processes with 1 thread each or 1 process with 10 threads. They all will be scheduled the same way. (Almost, with some exceptions which affect priorities, but not directly overall performance.)

Comment: Yes, I knew it was a bit broad but was looking to see if anyone had any experience. I believe your answer is basically correct. I wasn't sure if the ability to set a priority on an executing application was greater than for Tasks/threads.

Thanks for your response, I appreciate you taking the time.

Doug